# Place QWidget's windows to other (than main window) X DISPLAY

Tags: qt, window, x11, display, qwidget

I have a Qt GUI application. Need to place one window presented as QWidget object to other X DISPLAY. For example `:1`. Main window and others always run on DISPLAY got from environment.

How to place new QWindget window to other non-default X DIPSLAY.

*.thanks in adwance.*

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the connection to the X11 server is unique per process, and managed by the xcb QPA plugin. Hence, you can't just move a widget to another display.

I would suggest two possible approaches:

1. **Forking**: You split your application in two, separate programs, one running on one display, one running on the other, and use IPC to pass data between the two;
2. **XRandr**: Configure the X11 server so that multiple monitors are part of the same X11 DISPLAY, so you can freely re-arrange windows as you like;

Comment: 2 is already implemented and it is not what we need because of some reasons.

Comment: *managed by the xcb QPA plugin* - yes they are. May be I need to refer its docs. thanks